# implicit keyword in Play Action

Tags: scala, playframework

Can someone explain to me what's the use of implicit keyword in the following Play Action:

```
     def index = Action { implicit request =>
      Async {
      val cursor = collection.find(
      BSONDocument(), BSONDocument()).cursor[Patient] 
      val futureList = cursor.toList 
      futureList.map { patients => Ok(Json.toJson(patients)) } 
     }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all Scala (not just Play), an argument to an anonymous function can be marked `implicit` just as with methods. Within the body of the function, the `implicit` parameter is visible and can be resolved to an appropriate value in scope.

In this case, `request` is the argument of the anonymous function that describes what the action will do. The `implicit` lets the function be called with any value of type `Request` that happens to be in scope so you don't have to provide the `Request` instance yourself. You can trust it will be there so you can focus on the work of handling the request.